# Multiple joins in SQL query okay? Or is there a better way?

Tags: sql, mariadb

Is this a common way to get information from different tables over IDs (parent-child) in one query? There are also 6 more joins but I cut it off... or do you actually do it differently?

```
select *

from 
    ((((((((car 
left join 
    family on car.Family_ID = family.Family_ID) 
Left Join 
     material on car.Material_ID = material.Material_ID) 
Left Join 
    contactperson on car.ContactPerson_ID = contactperson.ContactPerson_ID) 
Left Join 
    customercontract on car.CustomerContract_ID = customercontract.CustomerContract_ID) 
Left Join 
    customerplant on car.CustomerPlant_ID = customerplant.CustomerPlant_ID)
```

Comment: All those parentheses are completely useless

Comment: so i dont need these? but the code itself?

Comment: If you want to see data from all those tables, then yes that's the way to do it

Comment: If you want information from a table then it must be listed in the `FROM` clause of your SQL. You must also establish the relationship between the two (or more tables) using a `JOIN` and `ON` clause. So this is the right way to go. Sometimes SQL gets really verbose, but that is it's nature.

Comment: @Martin Smith: That's 1:n as you can see from `car.Material_ID`, `car.ContactPerson_ID`, etc.

Comment: @Mr.Shazam: It depends on what you want to select. You are using outer joins. Inner joins are more common, but in some situations we need outer joins. And sometimes we'd use `EXISTS` or `IN` instead, if we only want to look up data in some table.

Comment: @Mr.Shazam . . . Tag the question with the databse you are using.

Comment: Use `LEFT` only if the row in the 'right' table is optional.  Beware of "over-normalizing"; 12 JOINs seems excessive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All those parenthesis don't hurt the logic, but are confusing and could be error prone.

Also, I would suggest you use aliases for each table, so it's easier to read and to debug.

Your query could look like:

```
select *
from car c
left join family f on c.Family_ID = f.Family_ID
left join material m on c.Material_ID = m.Material_ID
left join contactperson p on c.ContactPerson_ID = p.ContactPerson_ID
left join customercontract t on c.CustomerContract_ID = t.CustomerContract_ID
left join customerplant a on c.CustomerPlant_ID = a.CustomerPlant_ID
```

Comment: Also, try not to use `select *`. Only take the columns you actually need. And make sure that all the id's are indexed.

Comment: the impaler and @Noceo thank you, all IDs are indexed and I will only use coumns that i need!